# Problem with printing elements of enumerate function in python

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.8

This is a part of my python application code which is located in a for loop itself. It finds every file's name from another text file.

When I print `i` it prints the right line number every time. The problem is with the `sen`. When I print `sen`, it prints just a new line(`\n`). Why doesn't it contain every line's content?

```
line_number=1
for line in open(relevant_docs_path, "r",encoding="utf8"):
  
  if line.rstrip('\n') == file_name:
    with open(relevant_docs_path) as fp:
      for i, sen in enumerate(fp):
        if i == line_number+1:
          print(sen)
    break
  else:
    line_number += 1
```

and this is my text file(fp):

```
1.persian_query
7894.persian_poem 7895.persian_poem 7898.persian_poem 7899.persian_poem 7900.persian_poem

2.persian_query
7901.persian_poem 7902.persian_poem

3.persian_query
7901.persian_poem 7902.persian_poem

4.persian_query
7903.persian_poem

5.persian_query
7904.persian_poem 7905.persian_poem 7906.persian_poem 7907.persian_poem 7908.persian_poem 7909.persian_poem 7910.persian_poem 7911.persian_poem 7912.persian_poem 7913.persian_poem 7914.persian_poem 7915.persian_poem 7916.persian_poem 7917.persian_poem 7918.persian_poem 7919.persian_poem 7920.persian_poem 7921.persian_poem 7922.persian_poem 7923.persian_poem 7924.persian_poem
```

Comment: can you show the text file?

Comment: @coderoftheday I put the text file above

Comment: Why are you opening the same file twice ?

Comment: Trying different solutions to solve this problem, i came upon such thing :). i will edit it later. i don't think it makes a problem in the code @BcK

Comment: Mentality like this and you can open the same file hundred times. It's not about making a problem, it's about clean coding.

Comment: I know that. I'm trying to debug the code at the moment and find out what causes this problem. This is not the final code. It's just a test code @BcK

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that `enumerate` starts counting at 0 while `line_number` is initialized at 1. You need to either change `line_number` to 0 or use `enumarate(..., start=1)`.

Updated code:

```
line_number = 1
for line in open(relevant_docs_path, "r", encoding="utf8"):
  if line.rstrip('\n') == file_name:
    with open(relevant_docs_path) as fp:
      for i, sen in enumerate(fp, start=1):
        if i == line_number+1:
          print(sen)
    break
  else:
    line_number += 1
```

Comment: I have tried this before. It doesn't work. Do u have any other idea? :/

Comment: @samiravz: The same is true for `line` in the code as well. You need to add `readlines()` there as well.

Comment: I did it and it doesn't work. I think the problem is that the enumerate, reads the next line somehow, which is an empty line. but I don't know how does it happen.  @Shaido

Comment: @samiravz: I updated the answer. The problem with the line numbering is that `enumerate` starts counting at 0 while `line_number` starts at 1.

Comment: One does *not* have to explicitly read a file. A file object is already an iterator over the lines in the file. Reading a file explicitly stores the entire content in memory and is usually the wrong thing to do.

Comment: I changed the `line_number` value to zero and it is solved. Thanks a lot :) @Shaido

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: Yes, you are correct. I should have checked before assuming that was the problem here... I updated the answer with the solution to the actual problem.